# Android NDK make file

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am trying to execute a sample in ndk,but getting the following error.

```
Android NDK: There is no Android.mk under mp3solutions/jni
Android NDK: If this is intentional  please define APP_BUILD_SCRIPT to point
Android NDK: to a valid NDK build script.
android-ndk-r5b/build/core/add-application.mk:1
26: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

so please guide me how to resolve this one

Answer (score 0):

are you having `Android.mk` in your JNI folder?, see NDK-build the files which are all listed in **Android.mk**, so just be sure to have Android.mk file

Comment: i have already placed android.mk file in my JNI folder..but the ndk build is unable to detect that file...and can u give me any info regarding app_build_script...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file application.mk.If you do have  than please delete that file.Sometimes the path specified in the application.mk file causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and this is because mistaken I named file **Andorid.mk** instead **Android.mk**. This work for me.